# VirtualHost - Server not found

Tags: apache2, virtualhost

I'm running different websites on my webserver using Apache VirtualHosts. Now I have troubles getting one site to work. When I browse to the site in Firefox it says "Firefox can't find the server at www.mydomain.com", even though it's spelled correctly.

Further traceroute and ping both resolve to the correct IP, so I doubt it is because of a DNS issue.

**I copied the VirtualHost-config file from a working site** and just changed the domains and path on the server, which is existent. Further I checked that the site is enabled (with a2ensite), restartet apache, reloaded apache, but it is still not working.

Here's my VirtualHost-File:

```
<VirtualHost censored_ip:80>
  ServerName mydomain.com
  ServerAlias mydomain.com www.mydomain.com
  ServerAdmin <myemail>
  DocumentRoot /var/www/efin/
  <Directory /var/www/efin/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
  </Directory>
  ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error_efin.log
  LogLevel warn
  CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined
  ServerSignature On
</VirtualHost>
```

I hope someone can find the error here, since I have no idea where to look for it anymore. Thanks a lot in advance. I'd be happy to provide further information if needed.

Sincerely, Michael

Comment: This question will have better answers on [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com/)

Comment: thanks, posted it to http://serverfault.com/questions/294847/virtual-host-server-not-found

Comment: answered at http://serverfault.com/questions/294847/virtual-host-server-not-found